# nodejs server free array memory allocation

Tags: javascript, node.js

It's my first time creating a Nodejs server, I have noticed that global variable values are persistent between different queries to the server, that made me think ***should I clear arrays or do any thing else for reducing memory usage?***

For example if I have an array(declared inside a function) that get pushed with values and get logged to `response.send(JSON.stringify(array))`, should I set it to null after the function call?

Furthermore is there a better way to handle the end of connection/request/response in Nodejs to reduce memory usage?

```
...
code
...

if (results.length > 0) {
    var cur_data = {};
    cur_data["day"] = day_i;
    cur_data["data"] = results;
    ret_val.push(cur_data);
}

...
code
...

finish(con, req, res, JSONstringfy(ret_val), false);
ret_val = null;

function finish(con, req, res, log, is_error)
{
    req.pause();
    res.status(is_error == true ? 400 : 200);
    res.send(log);
    con.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is inside the function, you don't need to be worry because as soon as function finish its execution it release its resources. 
But if you declared the array outside the functions and pushing element in it on every request then you need to take action because it is saving globally.